# Would like to dispute Duplicate Label-Chain Rule of Limits

Tags: support, specific-question, exact-duplicates, re-open

I asked a question looking for a **epsilon-delta proof** for the Chain Rule of Limits, however the question was marked as a duplicate for a similar question but it does not provide the proof I was looking for. In fact someone had already mentioned before that it wasn't really a duplicate. I would like to get this question reopened. Is there an appeal or request I can make?

The link to the question is below:
[How to Prove the Chain Rule for Limits Using a $\varepsilon-\delta$ Argument?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581811/how-to-prove-the-chain-rule-for-limits)